# Alembic в проекте django

Tags: python, django, alembic

Всем привет, подскажите можно ли использовать Alembic  в проекте django и как это сделать.

В статьях Intern..  вижу что с Flask можно, устанавливаю pip install flask-migrate

А как включить миграцию c Alembic в Django в место  django migrations

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы похожи на очень эксцентричного человека, расскажите, пожалуйста а чем не устроили обычные миграции? Или это "зарядка для хвоста"? Фласк - оно понятно, минималистичный микрофреймворк, даем возможность принимать и обрабатывать http запросы - в остальном разбирайтесь сами. Другое дело джанга - старается предусмотреть инструментарий на, **буквально, все** случаи жизни вебразработчика. Лично я порылся в интернете и нашел какой-то такой проект https://github.com/shosca/django-sorcery, который делает что-то этакое. Это вообще похоже на то, что надо?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17964209/alembic-django-flask-migrate-database здесь у чувака есть 2 бекенда, один на фласке, другой на джанге - оба смотрят в одну базу и он пытался их подружить. Какое-то отчаянное положение.

Comment: Мое мнение - лучше не делать это без непреодолимых причин. Это породит страшные костыли, что вы забудете, зачем это все вообще делали. Пресловутые 99% причин - преодолимые. Проясните, пожалуйста, ваше намерение?